# Nginx with multiple layers of proxy_pass slowdown?

Tags: nginx

I'm using a single nginx.exe setup to do multiple proxy_pass but it seems it is causing a delay in the actual server receiving messages. This is what I mean: Nginx Load Balancer -> Upstream to Nginx Master Server Upstream to -> Child Server. I plan for multiple master servers if necessary to scale. When I test it out, the messages gets through but I have to wait a bit. At least 1 minute. I am not sure what settings I need to change in the config file to make it more instant. I tried running different Nginx.exe instances each with it's own config file but it still results in the same delay. All this is being tested on 1 machine. Both tcp and http proxy result in slowdown.

My config file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {
    #loginServerLoadBalancer
    server {
        listen 3000;
        proxy_pass loginServerMaster;
    }

    #loginServerMasters
    upstream loginServerMaster {
        server localhost:3100;
    }

    #loginServerMaster
    server {
        listen 3100;
        proxy_pass loginServerChild;
    }

    #loginServerChilds
    upstream loginServerChild {
        server localhost:3101;
        server localhost:3102;
        server localhost:3103;
        server localhost:3104;
        server localhost:3105;
        server localhost:3106;
        server localhost:3107;
        server localhost:3108;
    }

    #matchmakingServerLoadBalancer
    server {
        listen 3400;
        proxy_pass matchmakingServerMaster;
    }

    #matchmakingServerMasters
    upstream matchmakingServerMaster {
        server localhost:3500;
    }

    #matchmakingServerMaster
    server {
        listen 3500;
        proxy_pass matchmakingServerChild;
    }

    #matchmakingServerChilds
    upstream matchmakingServerChild {
        server localhost:3501;
        server localhost:3502;
        server localhost:3503;
        server localhost:3504;
        server localhost:3505;
        server localhost:3506;
        server localhost:3507;
        server localhost:3508;
    }

    #gameServerLoadBalancer
    server {
        listen 3600;
        proxy_pass gameServerMaster;
    }

    #gameServerMasters
    upstream gameServerMaster {
        server localhost:3700;
    }

    #gameServerMaster
    server {
        listen 3700;
        proxy_pass gameServerChild;
    }

    #gameServerChilds
    upstream gameServerChild {
        server localhost:3701;
        server localhost:3702;
        server localhost:3703;
        server localhost:3704;
        server localhost:3705;
        server localhost:3706;
        server localhost:3707;
        server localhost:3708;
    }
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #loginServerLoadBalancer
    server {
        listen       3050;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://loginServerMaster;
        }
    }

    #loginServerMasters
    upstream loginServerMaster {
        server localhost:3150;
    }

    #loginServerMaster
    server {
        listen       3150;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://loginServerChild;
        }
    }

    #loginServerChilds
    upstream loginServerChild {
        server localhost:3151;
        server localhost:3152;
        server localhost:3153;
        server localhost:3154;
        server localhost:3155;
        server localhost:3156;
        server localhost:3157;
        server localhost:3158;
    }

    #dataServerLoadBalancer
    server {
        listen       3200;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://dataServerMaster;
        }
    }

    #dataServerMasters
    upstream dataServerMaster {
        server localhost:3300;
    }

    #dataServerMaster
    server {
        listen       3300;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://dataServerChild;
        }
    }

    #dataServerChilds
    upstream dataServerChild {
        server localhost:3301;
        server localhost:3302;
        server localhost:3303;
        server localhost:3304;
        server localhost:3305;
        server localhost:3306;
        server localhost:3307;
        server localhost:3308;
    }

    #regular server
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #login server load balance via child process
        #location /oauth2 {
        #   proxy_pass http://oauth2;
        #}
        #location /data {
        #   proxy_pass http://data;
        #}

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /cloud/www;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /cloud/www;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Comment: Do not use nginx for windows http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: Have you tried to set off the proxy_buffering?.

Comment: tried proxy_buffering off but does not work. I am developing on windows since it is more convenient as the client side development software is also on windows. However, during deployment time, I will switch to a linux version of nginx which may resolve the issue. Not using nginx for windows is not a solution to this problem however.